# Contiki: Why is a linker script for cc253x not present?

Tags: linker, makefile, contiki

I was going through the codes of Contiki for cc2530, i find that a linker script is missing for cc2530. Can anybody tell me how it works without a linker script?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look on this [Makefile](https://github.com/g-oikonomou/contiki-sensinode/blob/cc-ports/cpu/cc253x/Makefile.cc253x#L185).

```
%.banked-hex: %.flags
### Link again with new bank allocations
@echo "\nFinal Link"
@echo "==============="
$(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(shell cat $<) -o $@ $(CONTIKI_TARGET_MAIN) $(OBJECTDIR)/$*.app.rel -llibsdcc.lib -lcontiki-$(TARGET).lib > /dev/null
```

Is this a final link script as you mean?